# Creating a script with List

Tags: c#, scripting

I'm attempting to create a script with `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting`.
As soon as I add `List<>` the code errors. I thought I had all the necessary references and usings included, however it still errors stating `The type or namespace name 'List<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?`

These are my usings in the code

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Diagnostics;
```

Below is my example unit test

```
[TestMethod]
public void RunGenericListTest()
{
    var code = @"
List<string> strings = new List<string>();
strings.Add(""test string"");            
return output;";

    var options = ScriptOptions.Default;

    options.WithReferences(typeof(System.Collections.CollectionBase).Assembly);
    options.WithReferences(typeof(System.Collections.Generic.List<>).Assembly);
    options.WithImports("System.Collections");
    options.WithImports("System.Collections.Generic");

    var result = CSharpScript.RunAsync(code, options).Result;

    Debug.WriteLine(result);
}
```

This errors on the `CSharpScript.RunAsync` every time. Can someone enlighten me on what I'm missing?

Comment: Fair play for including a unit test. It's nice to see questions with minimal, reproducible examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is, `WithImports` does not mutate options but rather [returns a copy](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Scripting/Core/ScriptOptions.cs#L318)

```
var code = @"
List<string> strings = new List<string>();
strings.Add(""test string"");            
return strings;";

    var options = ScriptOptions.Default
                .WithImports("System.Collections.Generic"); // chaining methods would work better here.
    // alternatively reassign the variable:
    // options = options.WithImports("System.Collections.Generic");

    var result = CSharpScript.RunAsync(code, options).Result;

    Debug.WriteLine((result.ReturnValue as List<string>).First());
```

Comment: So its a syntax error. I didn't realise that the `options` wasn't being added to if you didn't reassign it to itself. The `returns a copy` link was a little difficult to understand initially but was also helpful. Thanks

Comment: @Thundter I'm sorry I couldn't find this class in the documentation. Had to go to the source